# Implementing custom loss that makes use of training batch data with Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement a GAN called the SimGAN proposed by Apple researchers. The SimGAN is used to refine *labelled* synthetic images so that they look more like the *unlabelled* real images.

The link to the paper can be found on arXiv [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1612.07828.pdf).

In the paper, the loss function of the combined model, which comprises the generator and the discriminator, has a self-regularization component in the form of an `L1 loss` that penalizes too great a difference between the synthetic images and the images after refinement. In other words, the refinement should not be too drastic.

I would like to know how I can implement this self-regularization loss in `Keras`. Here is what I tried:

```
def self_regularization_loss(refined_images, syn_images):
    
    def l1loss(y_true, y_pred):
        return keras.metrics.mean_absolute_error(refined_images, syn_images)
        
    return l1loss
```

However, I do not think I can compile the model in the way below as the batches of refined and synthetic images change during training time.

```
model.compile(loss=[self_regularization_loss(current_batch_of_refined, current_batch_of_synthetic),
                    local_adversarial_loss],
              optimizer=opt)
```

What is the way to implement this loss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying using the `tf.function` decorator and `tf.GradientTape()`:

```
@tf.function
def train_step(model, batch):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        refined_images, syn_images = batch
        loss = self_regularization_loss(model, refined_images, syn_images)

    gradients = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))
```

your training loop can look something like:

```
for image_batch in dataset:
  train_step(model, image_batch)
```

Here it is assumed that `model` is of type `tf.keras.Model`. More details to the model class can be found [here](https://keras.io/api/models/model/). Note that `model` is also passed to `self_regularization_loss`. In this function your `model` recieves both images as inputs and then gives you the respective output. Then you calculate your loss.